# How can I substitute TRNG probabilities in R?

Tags: r, random

I have a hardware true random number generator. It has very high performance. When I run the output via ENT I get the following report:

> Total:    1073741824   1.000000
>
> Entropy = 8.000000 bits per byte.
>
> Optimum compression would reduce the size of this 1073741824 byte file
>   by 0 percent.
>
> Chi square distribution for 1073741824 samples is 247.87, and randomly
>   would exceed this value 61.38 percent of the times.
>
> Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.4957 (127.5 = random).
>   Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.141666379 (error 0.00 percent). Serial
>   correlation coefficient is 0.000056 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).

In R I have been taking the random bytes and using them in sample as a probability vector.

This takes the form of `sample(x, size, replace=FALSE, prob=myprobvector)` which works fine until I test the entropy of it and find out it is not much better than the Mersenne-Twister, which gives 99.9% entropy efficiency. In my case I am using a base of 75 choices so Log2(75) = 6.22881869. The entropy of MT approach is 6.223578221 and with the vector it is 6.223578468. I believe It is still using MT and just using the probability vector to add weight and move things around. How can I get it to use just the values off the hardware? (Assume they are being read like a file.)

Comment: I have noticed that it is possible to specify user supplied information to the arguments of `RNGkind`, so it might be possible to do something along those lines.  Perhaps `?RNG` and `?Random.user` might offer some clues?

Comment: I was looking at that! There is a possibility of using C code to make your own RNG. This would be great if I had constant access to the TRNG hardware. However, I am currently using a 1GB extract from the device. I also think the problem is not as simple as it looks. The issue could be that I am trying to measure the entropy of several sub processes as if they were one.